# Django Rest API - Get & Verify User ID by token

Tags: django, api

How to obtain User ID from Django API having authentication token? Basically, I want to send an authentication token and get back the User id. Basically I want to verify the company id that must be call by Django rest API!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have token based authentication, `self.context['request'].user` will return the authenticated user according to the provided token.

Comment: Basically I am new in Django! Can you please such kind of documnetaion or youtube tutorial reference?

Comment: Do you have some piece of code to look at ?

Comment: No, I just want to learn it from scratch!

Comment: I guess you have at least created a Django app right ? Then attach the views.py and serializers.py code to the question.